# Get overscroll amount in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to know the overscroll amount in Compose for a lazy column?
I'm using `drawBehind` but the drawn rectangle I add there doesn't 'stretch' with the overscroll effect, so there is a visible gap.

I know the 'stretchy' overscroll effect is only for the latest versions of Android. I tried setting a custom `LocalOverscrollConfiguration` though that doesn't seem to change anything for newer versions of Android that use the new stretch effect.